# Python: how to add multiple patches on bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to visualize different patches in `bokeh`. Let say `source` and `source1`.

```
    p = figure(plot_width=800)
    p.patches('x', 'y', source = source, fill_color='white', fill_alpha=0.5, 
line_color="black", line_width=1)

    p.patches('x', 'y', source = source1, fill_color='white', fill_alpha=0.5, 
line_color="black", line_width=1)
```

If I do that I am only able to visualize the `source1`. Is there a way to add multiple layers?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `source = source1` in the second patch command?

Comment: @Sheldore yes, it was a typo. But it does not change the result

Comment: that would mean your source and source1 are the same, or they completely overlap.

Comment: `source` and `source1` are not the same and they don't completely overlap